# Get GlProgram binary from Cg vertex shader

Tags: opengl, binary, cg, vertex-shader

I have some Cg Vertex shader and want to get the compiled binary from it to cache.

The way I load the Cg vertex is using glProgramStringARB, the problem with that is that I can't retrieve any value from glGetProgramiv and glGetProgramBinary.

Here is a example code of what I'm doing:

```
CGprogram program = cgCreateProgram(context, CG_SOURCE, source, ...);
const char* programARB = static_cast<char*>(cgGetProgramString(program,
  CG_COMPILED_PROGRAM));
GLuint id;
glGenProgramsARB(1, id);
glBindProgramARB(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_ARB, id);
glProgramStringARB(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_ARB, GL_PROGRAM_FORMAT_ASCII_ARB,
  static_cast<GLsizei>(strlen(programARB)), programARB);
GLint length = -10;
glGetProgramiv(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_ARB, GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_LENGTH, &lenght);
printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);
```

I initialized length with -10 just to see if the variable would change with glGetProgramiv call, but I always get the -10 as result.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem with that is that I can't retrieve any value from glGetProgramiv and glGetProgramBinary.

Of course you can't. You're confusing ARB_vertex_program with *GLSL programs*. They're *not* the same thing.

[`glGetProgramiv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgram) takes a GLSL program object (among other things). Odds are good that OpenGL is giving you a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error, since the first argument is almost certainly not a valid program object created by [`glCreateProgram`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCreateProgram).

You can't get a program binary for an ARB_vertex_program. You would need to compile your Cg shader to GLSL, then use [the standard GLSL compile/link process](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Object), and get the binary from *that*.